# Question about vba in PPT(Microsoft PowerPoint )

Tags: vba

I want display a progress bar when showing ppt.
I write code like this:

```
Public WithEvents App As Application
Private Sub App_SlideShowNextSlide(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
    Dim Showpos As Integer
    Showpos = Wn.View.CurrentShowPosition
    Dim PageCount As Integer
    PageCount = Application.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    SlideShowWindows(Index:=1).View.PointerType = ppSlideShowPointerPen
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 15
        Wn.View.DrawLine 0, i, 700 * Showpos / PageCount, i
    Next

End Sub
```

using above code, a progress bar appear when I show the PPT.
But when I turn to next slide，The progress bar appear and disappear quickly.I wonder why it happens.And how to prevent the progress bar disappearing.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of ugly, but you could turn off the screen updating in between slides:
http://skp.mvps.org/ppt00033.htm